# C# Equivalent to Java's Runtime.getRuntime.exec()

Tags: c#, taskkill

Is there a C # Equivalent to  Java's `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`?

I can't seem to find an equivalent in the IntelliSense. If there is such a thing, is there a specific `using` directive I need to reference?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start I suppose.

Comment: before the question is edited, are you looking for `Process.Start()`?

Comment: No I am running Selenium Webdriver and I am trying to kill any webdrivers  before the start of a new test.  I used Runtime.getRuntime.exec() when using Java and that worked but can't find an equivalent for C#

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution thanks to

[How to kill IEDriverServer.exe console window after running an InternetExplorerDriver Selenium test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186875/how-to-kill-iedriverserver-exe-console-window-after-running-an-internetexplorerd)

Right before I call my webdriver I run

```
  foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("IEDriverServer"))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
```

This did the trick, which was a little different then Java syntax, thats why I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start("C:\\")) 
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Note : C:\ should be replaced by the path of your .exe file location
ex : C:\test\myfile.exe